# How to make screen bigger in byobu

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, byobu, terminal-multiplexer

My new server install looks odd:
[image]

is there anyway to resize it to use the whole terminal window?

Comment: This madness is finally over! I was cursing those dots where messed up with my highly sophisticate activity, namely copy & paste.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This means that there is another ssh or terminal client, other than yourself, connected to this session, which has a smaller window size than yours.

You can detach all clients but yourself, using this [Byobu](http://byobu.co) hotkey:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>

Or you can run the script `/usr/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client`

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I'd upvote you, but I don't have the reputation for it, thank you, it never occurred to me that I'd left myself logged in after I was done setting up the network.

Comment: Alt - F6 did not work for me, but the script does.

Comment: This shortcut and this command does not work for me... I am using screen and not tmux...

Comment: Some distros may not include that script - you can download it here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/master/usr/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client

Comment: Doing the Alt - F6 on my Macbook Air while Mosh'ing into my server caused me to disconnect as well ;(

Comment: Most OS capture the `Alt`-`F6` and don't pass it to the terminal window, hence why it doesn't work for some.

Comment: Awesome tool. The command works fine for me! Thank you for your work!

Comment: I have a vague recollection of being able to force a resize, effectively causing windows in other sessions to be _bigger_ than their terminal. Perhaps I was using `screen`. Anyway, is there any such feature in byobu?

Comment: For anyone with the issue of subsequent sessions attaching to the current session see [my solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160543/intellij-embedded-terminal-sharing-buffer-with-byobu) dealing with IntelliJ terminal attaching to my regular terminal's session

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to `Alt-F6` is `Prefix-Shift-D`, where `Prefix` is your byobu escape command (typically `Ctrl-a`).

See more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138211/how-do-i-disconnect-all-other-users-in-tmux.

Answer (score 8):

Alt-F6 did not work for me. But I found that I was using tmux. To detach the other window use a combination of list-clients and detach-client:

```
% tmux list-clients
/dev/pts/1: 0 [64x160 xterm] (utf8)
/dev/pts/39: 0 [39x143 xterm] (utf8)
% tmux detach-client -t /dev/pts/39
```

Since the 64x160 is larger, I figured that was my window while the other client was the smaller one.

Comment: This works like a charm. Tried the accepted one and didn't work, but this one did. Good job.

Comment: This seems to do the exact same thing as `/usr/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client`. For me the smaller client "disappears for maybe 3 seconds, then comes back. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Fantastic script!  On OSX using byobu installed with Homebrew, it's (currently)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/byobu/5.92/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client
```

presumably you'd modify the version number, but that's to give you an idea of how to find it

`brew info byobu` will tell you where byobu stores its lib etc files.

then just append the `lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client` to whatever that location is (in my case, `/usr/local/Cellar/byobu/5.92/`)

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the script (`tmux-detach-all-but-current-client`) and `alt-F6`. None of them worked. The terminal only went fullscreen for a couple of seconds, then it went back to small size (like in the image in the original post).
I also checked users with `w`, it was only me logged in.

What ended up working for me, was simply disabling Byobu and enabling Byobu again, with a logout/in in between. Like so:

`byobu-disable`
`exit`
Login again
`byobu-enable`

Screen is back to normal.

Answer (score -2):

I got it to work sending the command via  vim Sepcial chars
on your preference keys on iterm2
\033[17;3~

[image: here is image that show the configuration]